# Can we say a sports club transferred a player if they received the player?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

As far as I know, if a sports club gives a player to another sports club, we can say the club that gave the player to the other transferred him or her like in, "Arsenal transferred two of their players last week". My question is, can we also say "transfer" referring to the action by the team that got the player? Can we say they transferred a player if they are the team that got the player? For example, let's say the soccer club Arsenal signed a new player. Can we say, "Arsenal transferred a player", referring to the action of getting a player?

Answer (score 2):

From Collins English Dictionary:

> In professional sports, if **a player transfers** or **is transferred** from one club to another, they leave one club and begin playing for another:
>
> 1. He transferred from Spurs to Middlesbrough.
> 2. He was transferred from Crystal Palace to Arsenal.

So, a club with a new player doesn't transfer the player, but the player transfers to the club.

Comment: Thanks. What if we use "from"? Don't you think "Arsenal transferred a new player from Manchester United", would be okay?

Comment: @FireandIce to me, it sounds unnatural.

Comment: @FireandIce you know, I guess that's because Arsenal is not really in the position to make someone else's player change their team. It's up to the team the player originally plays for, the "employer", if you will. So, Arsenal can possibly obtain a player, but Arsenal can only transfer its own players somewhere.

Comment: I see. Thank you.